# Combine turn one Publisher into another

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I use an OAuth framework which creates authenticated requests asynchronously like so:

```
OAuthSession.current.makeAuthenticatedRequest(request: myURLRequest) { (result: Result<URLRequest, OAuthError>) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let request):
                URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
                    // ...
                }
             // ...
             }
        }
```

I am trying to make my OAuth framework use Combine, so I know have a Publisher version of the `makeAuthenticatedRequest` method i.e.:

```
public func makeAuthenticatedRequest(request: URLRequest) -> AnyPublisher<URLRequest, OAuthError>
```

I am trying to use this to replace the call site above like so:

```
OAuthSession.current.makeAuthenticatedRequestPublisher(request)
    .tryMap(URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for:))
    .tryMap { (data, _) in data } // Problem is here
    .decode(type: A.self, decoder: decoder)
```

As noted above, the problem is on turning the result of the publisher into a new publisher. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to use `flatMap`, not `tryMap`, around `dataTaskPublisher(for:)`.

Look at the types. Start with this:

```
let p0 = OAuthSession.current.makeAuthenticatedRequest(request: request)
```

Option-click on `p0` to see its deduced type. It is `AnyPublisher<URLRequest, OAuthError>`, since that is what `makeAuthenticatedRequest(request:)` is declared to return.

Now add this:

```
let p1 = p0.tryMap(URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for:))
```

Option-click on `p1` to see its deduced type, `Publishers.TryMap<AnyPublisher<URLRequest, OAuthError>, URLSession.DataTaskPublisher>`. Oops, that's a little hard to understand. Simplify it by using `eraseToAnyPublisher`:

```
let p1 = p0
    .tryMap(URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for:))
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Now the deduced type of `p1` is `AnyPublisher<URLSession.DataTaskPublisher, Error>`. That still has the somewhat mysterious type `URLSession.DataTaskPublisher` in it, so let's erase that too:

```
let p1 = p0.tryMap {
    URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: $0)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher() }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Now Xcode can tell us that the deduced type of `p1` is `AnyPublisher<AnyPublisher<URLSession.DataTaskPublisher.Output, URLSession.DataTaskPublisher.Failure>, OAuthError>`. Let me reformat that for readability:

```
AnyPublisher<
    AnyPublisher<
        URLSession.DataTaskPublisher.Output, 
        URLSession.DataTaskPublisher.Failure>,
    OAuthError>
```

It's a publisher that publishes publishers that publish `URLSession.DataTaskPublisher.Output`.

That's not what you expected, and it's why your second `tryMap` fails. You thought you were creating a publisher of `URLSession.DataTaskPublisher.Output` (which is a `typealias` for the tuple `(data: Data, response: URLResponse)`), and that's the input your second `tryMap` wants. But Combine thinks your second `tryMap`'s input should be a `URLSession.DataTaskPublisher`.

When you see this kind of nesting, with a publisher that publishes publishers, it means you probably needed to use `flatMap` instead of `map` (or `tryMap`). Let's do that:

```
let p1 = p0.flatMap {
       //   ^^^^^^^ flatMap instead of tryMap
    URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: $0)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher() }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Now we get a compile-time error:

> Instance method 'flatMap(maxPublishers:_:)' requires the types 'OAuthError' and 'URLSession.DataTaskPublisher.Failure' (aka 'URLError') be equivalent

The problem is that Combine can't flatten the nesting because the outer publisher's failure type is `OAuthError` and the inner publisher's failure type is `URLError`. Combine can only flatten them if they have the same failure type. We can fix this problem by converting both failure types to the general `Error` type:

```
let p1 = p0
    .mapError { $0 as Error }
    .flatMap {
        URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: $0)
            .mapError { $0 as Error }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher() }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

This compiles, and Xcode tells us that the deduced type is `AnyPublisher<URLSession.DataTaskPublisher.Output, Error>`, which is what we want. We can tack on your next `tryMap`, but let's just use `map` instead because the body can't throw any errors:

```
let p2 = p1.map { $0.data }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Xcode tells us `p2` is an `AnyPublisher<Data, Error>`, so we could then chain a `decode` modifier.

Now that we have straightened out the types, we can get rid of all the type erasers and put it all together:

```
OAuthSession.current.makeAuthenticatedRequest(request: request)
    .mapError { $0 as Error }
    .flatMap {
        URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: $0)
            .mapError { $0 as Error } }
    .map { $0.data }
    .decode(type: A.self, decoder: decoder)
```

Comment: I wish I could give more than 1 upvote to this answer. It is very crisp and clear! Thank you, rob