# Trouble posting API request with Combine

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I'm new to the `Combine` game and am trying to figure out how to generalize a HTTP `POST` request.

I created the following `APIService` class to extend individual resource services from:

```swift
import Foundation
import Combine

class APIService {
  let decoder: JSONDecoder
  let session: URLSession
  
  init(session: URLSession = URLSession.shared, decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()) {
    self.decoder = decoder
    self.session = session
  }
}

// MARK: JSON API
extension APIService {
  struct Response<T> {
    let response: HTTPURLResponse
    let value: T
  }
  
  func post<T: Codable>(
    payload: T,
    url: URL
  ) -> AnyPublisher<Response<T>, APIError> {
    return Just(payload)
      .setFailureType(to: APIError.self) // <<< THIS WAS MISSING!
      .encode(encoder: JSONEncoder())
      .flatMap({ [weak self] payload -> AnyPublisher<Data, Error> in
        guard let self = self else {
          return Fail(error: .default("Failing to establish self.")).eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = Methods.post
        request.setValue(
          Mimetypes.json,
          forHTTPHeaderField: Headers.contentType
        )
        request.httpBody = payload
        return self.session
          .dataTaskPublisher(
            for: request
          )
          .tryMap { response -> Response<T> in
            let value = try self.decoder.decode(T.self, from: response.data)
            return Response(
              value: value,
              response: response.response
            )
          }
          .mapError { error in
            return APIError.default(error.localizedDescription)
          }
          .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
          .eraseToAnyPublisher()
      })
      .eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }
}
```

However, this class won't compile with the following error at the `post` function.

```
Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

Being new to Swift in general and Combine in particular, I am unfortunately out of ideas on how to proceed.

**Any help is greatly appreciated!**

### Figured it out myself: Solution

Add a `Failure` type to the `Just`, so input and output `Failure` types to `flatMap` are equal. Or put differently: `flatMap` cannot convert the `Never` failing `Just` to a `Publisher` with `Failure`.

The missing line in my case:

```swift
Just(payload)
  .setFailureType(to: APIError.self)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have a few compile-time mistakes, which the Swift type inference system isn't able to pinpoint when they happen within a notoriously cranky `flatMap` Combine operator.

1. First, you're using the wrong order of parameters and the type of `URLResponse`, in creating a `Response` object. Correct it to:

```
return Response(
   response: response.response as! HTTPURLResponse,
   value: value
)
```

2. Second, your `flatMap` is not actually returning `AnyPublisher<Data, Error>` - the return type you specified inside its closure. The return type is `AnyPublisher<Response<T>, APIError>`. So, you can change that, but then you'll run into another problem, which is that the `Error` type of `flatMap` has to be the same as its upstream, which currently is not `APIError`, so I'd suggest just moving the `mapError` out of `flatMap`. It would look like this:

```
return Just(payload)
    .encode(encoder: JSONEncoder())
    .flatMap({ [weak self] payload -> AnyPublisher<Response<T>, Error> in
        guard let self = self else {
            return Fail(error: APIError.default("...")).eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "Methods.post"
        request.setValue(
            Mimetypes.json,
            forHTTPHeaderField: Headers.contentType
        )
        request.httpBody = payload
        return self.session
            .dataTaskPublisher(
                for: request
            )
            .tryMap { response -> Response<T> in
                let value = try self.decoder.decode(T.self, from: response.data)
                return Response(
                    response: response.response as! HTTPURLResponse,
                    value: value
                    )
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
            
    })
    .mapError { error in
        return APIError.default(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, thanks to [this solid guide to debugging Publishers on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57172058/5061949).

The `Just` needs to be augmented with a `Failure`, because `flatMap` needs the `Failure` of input and output streams to be the same.

We can use [`setFailureType(to: <T>)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/replaceerror/setfailuretype(to:)) to do so. I have updated my question to reflect this solution.